# Using kids shows? How original!

Tags: word, knowledge, rebus

> Something most of us will not escape from.

[image: kid's show character being snooty]

I've included the Knowledge tag since the character depicted above is not some creature I made up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could it be

> Arthritis?

because

> Arthur - Right - Is

Comment: Now to wait for another 15 minutes so I can check mark you :p

Comment: This rebus reminded me about [this episode](http://arthur.wikia.com/wiki/Crushed)...see quote about dancing the jitterbug ;P